# C++ Libraries for interacting with Amazon S3 using Visual Studio and Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, amazon-s3

I have data in S3 and I would like C++ libraries for Visual Studio 2010 and Windows 7 for fetching/interacting with that data. I have looked at many online open source libraries, but compiling them has been a nightmare due to the number of dependencies involved. Is there a step by step guide to do the same?

Comment: Why do you think C++ is correct choice for this? Any reason to prefer C++ over Java or Ruby?

Comment: We are developing a C++ driver on Windows, which needs S3 access. We are using an external SDK which is written in C++, so unfortunately we cannot avoid C++ in this case. Unfortunate, but nothing we can do :(